# MPI_Allreduce in Fortran mixes when same processors are summed up in the same bins

Tags: mpi

MPI_Allreduce mix elements in the sum

I am parallelising a fortran code which works with no problem in a no-MPI version. Below an excerpt of the code. Every processor does the following: for a certain number of particles it evolves certain quantities in the loop "do 203"; in a given interval which is divided in Nint subintervals (j=1,Nint), every processor produces an element of the vectors Nx1(j), Nx2(j). Then, the vectors Nx1(j), Nx2(j) are sent to the root (mype =0) which in every subinterval (j=1,Nint) sums all the contributions for every processor: Nx1(j) from processor 1 + Nx1(j) from processor 2.... The root sums for every value of j (every subinterval), and produces Nx5(j), Nx6(j). Another issue is that if I deallocate the variables the code remains in standby after the end of the calculation without completing the execution; but I don't know if this is related to the MPI_Allreduce issue.

```
include "mpif.h"
...

integer*4 ....

...

real*8 

...

call MPI_INIT(mpierr)

call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, npe, mpierr)

call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, mype, mpierr)


! Allocate variables allocate(Nx1(Nint),Nx5(Nint)) ...


! Parameters ...


call MPI_Barrier (MPI_COMM_WORLD, mpierr)


! Loop on particles


do 100 npartj=1,npart_local


 call init_random_seed() 

 call random_number (rand)


...

Initial condition

... 

do 203 i=1,1000000  ! loop for time evolution of single particle


    if(ufinp.gt.p1.and.ufinp.le.p2)then 

     do j=1,Nint  ! spatial position at any momentum

      ls(j) = lb+(j-1)*Delta/Nint !Left side of sub-interval across shock

      rs(j) = ls(j)+Delta/Nint

      if(y(1).gt.ls(j).and.y(1).lt.rs(j))then !position-ordered

        Nx1(j)=Nx1(j)+1 

      endif 

     enddo

    endif

   if(ufinp.gt.p2.and.ufinp.le.p3)then 

    do j=1,Nint  ! spatial position at any momentum

      ls(j) = lb+(j-1)*Delta/Nint !Left side of sub-interval across shock

      rs(j) = ls(j)+Delta/Nint

      if(y(1).gt.ls(j).and.y(1).lt.rs(j))then !position-ordered

        Nx2(j)=Nx2(j)+1 

      endif 

    enddo

   endif


203 continue 

100 continue

call MPI_Barrier (MPI_COMM_WORLD, mpierr)


print*,"To be summed"

do j=1,Nint

   call MPI_ALLREDUCE (Nx1(j),Nx5(j),npe,mpi_integer,mpi_sum, &
     &      MPI_COMM_WORLD, mpierr)
   call MPI_ALLREDUCE (Nx2(j),Nx6(j),npe,mpi_integer,mpi_sum, &
     &          MPI_COMM_WORLD, mpierr)

enddo 


if(mype.eq.0)then

do j=1,Nint

   write(1,107)ls(j),Nx5(j),Nx6(j)

 enddo 


107 format(3(F13.2,2X,i6,2X,i6))

endif 

call MPI_Barrier (MPI_COMM_WORLD, mpierr) 
print*,"Now deallocate" 

! deallocate(Nx1) 

!inserting the de-allocate 

! deallocate(Nx2)


close(1)


call MPI_Finalize(mpierr)


end


! Subroutines ...
```

Comment: I am sorry, I did not understand your question, could you explain what you expect your allreduces to do, and what they do different from that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MPI\_Allreduce mix elements in the sum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32495112/mpi-allreduce-mix-elements-in-the-sum)

Comment: I added the MPI tag to your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/32495112/577108), no need to ask the same thing multiple times.

Comment: @Haraldkl: I have N particles, each processors operates over npart_local particles.The space interval Delta is binned in Nint subintervals.On a single particle,the processor records the position of the particle at various times within Delta.If at time t the particle has velocity between p1 and p2 and it's located between ls(j) and rs(j), the counter Nx1(j) increases by 1. If the particle has velocity between p2 and p3, between ls(j) and rs(j), the counter Nx2(j) increases by 1. So every processor counts Nx1(j), Nx2(j)... allreduce sums all particles for every j and various velocities. Thanks